# What's the best way to load landscape and portrait xib files for uitableviewcells?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

My portrait tableviewcell doesn't work too well in landscape, even with an autoresize mask so I rearranged things with a new xib file.

What's the best way to implement this new landscape? I got it working using a bunch of if statements checking the orientation, but that doesn't seem too elegant. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two UITableViewCell nib files for portrait and landscape..and one custom class(CustomCell.h and CustomCell.m ) with UITableViewCell as the base class which the two NIB's will inherit and implement the following with your customized cells..

```
-(void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {


 if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customCell-Landscape" owner:self options:nil];

        }else
 {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customCell-Portrait" owner:self options:nil];

}

[tableView reloadData];

}
```

and then in the tableview datasource

```
..

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @" identifier";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customCell-Landscape" owner:self options:nil];
        }else {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customCell-Portrait" owner:self options:nil];
        }

    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to use a different cell-identifier name for the different xibs.

Comment: I think there is no need to load the custom cell nib in the -willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation method, you just call [tableView reloadData]; and in the -cellForRowAtIndexPath you load the convenient nib